# Why does this relative path work locally but fail in a container?

Tags: javascript, frontend, svelte, rollupjs

I am experiencing something strange and I was hoping someone more experienced could shed light on what is happening.

I have a frontend web project written in Svelte. I'm using rollup to compile and bundle the files. Rollup works great locally, I can build using `rollup -c` and it works perfectly.

However, when I run it in my [container](https://hub.docker.com/layers/sallaben/powershell_deploy/1.0/images/sha256-f798253d77c9943c4daaa6e1c3b79dd591a2fa9a0e794454af25a88f58d4135e?context=explore) I experience an error on build.

```
# npm run build

> app@1.0.0 build /__w/app-svelte/app-svelte
> rollup -c


src/main.js → public/build/bundle.js...
[!] Error: Could not resolve './routes/SignUpRoute.svelte' from src/App.svelte
Error: Could not resolve './routes/SignUpRoute.svelte' from src/App.svelte
    at error (/__w/app-svelte/app-svelte/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:161:30)
    at ModuleLoader.handleResolveId (/__w/app-svelte/app-svelte/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:17571:24)
    at /__w/app-svelte/app-svelte/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:17502:30
    at async Promise.all (index 7)
    at ModuleLoader.fetchModule (/__w/app-svelte/app-svelte/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:17531:9)
    at /__w/app-svelte/app-svelte/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:17500:36
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at ModuleLoader.fetchModule (/__w/app-svelte/app-svelte/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:17531:9)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

What could be causing this reference error? I verified that the file hierarchy in the container looks like this at the time of `npm run build` (irrelevant files excluded):

```
- public
- src
  - routes
    - SignUpRoute.svelte
  - App.svelte
```

Really at a loss here...

Comment: Are you using Windows or Mac?

Comment: @ThomasSablik My local environment is OSX and the container is based on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Could you try it with a Docker container in a Linux host? Docker with Windows or Mac can be "surprising".

Comment: I'll give it a shot, I'm curious what do you think that will change?

Comment: @ThomasSablik Oh, I am already using ubuntu docker container. So I'm not sure that would have any effect.

Comment: I'm just guessing but I learned it the hard way that Docker should be used on Linux. I have no concrete idea. You are using a Linux container on a Mac host. Try a Linux container on a Linux host or a Mac container on a Mac host.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm not running the container locally, I am running it on a remote ubuntu host and it's based on ubuntu.

Comment: My question is if this problem is related to Docker or to Linux. Are you able to build this project on a Linux without Docker? The problem could be a difference between paths on Mac and paths on Linux.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I solved it! Check out the answer I posted. Turned out not to be related to either of those, but I really appreciate the help as it was your question that led me to eventually find the difference in environments. Have a great evening.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, it actually wasn't related to my environment at all. I had committed the file as `SignupRoute.svelte` earlier and then changed it locally to `SignUpRoute.svelte`. Git was set to ignore case so it didn't pick up the change, and the container was pulling from the git repository. Problem solved, thanks @Thomas Sablik for the help!

`git config core.ignorecase false`

Comment: Wasted an entire day to find the issue. Without your post, there is no way I could have solved it! Thank you so much

Comment: This saved my recruitment task, thanks a lot!